# How to Import C++ vector data to Swift

Tags: c++, swift, vector

I have a C++ function that gets called by Swift that I need to return a vector of UIIMage's `std::vector<UIImage *>`. The only problem is I don't know how to retrieve the value of the vector.

C++ file 1:

```
//  OpenCVWrapper.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OpenCVWrapper : NSObject

+(???) convert:(UIImage *) image;

@end
```

file 2:

```
//  OpenCVWrapper.mm
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>

class Converter {
public:
    UIImage *image;        
    std::vector<UIImage *> main() {

        // run code 

        return finalImage;
    };

};

@implementation OpenCVWrapper

+(std::vector<UIImage *>) convert:(UIImage *)image {
    Converter converter;
    converter.image = image;
    std::vector<UIImage *>newImage = converter.main();

    return newImage;

}

@end
```

Swift:

```
var multipleImages = OpenCVWrapper.convert(originalImage) //want array
```

I'm aware Swift doesn't import c++ data structures, I'm looking to extract the values from the vector.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`std::vector::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)along with another parameter for the length usually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `std::vector` from Swift, so don't return a `std::vector`.

Since your vector contains instances of `UIImage`, simply return a `NSArray`:

```
+ ( NSArray< UIImage * > * )convert: ( UIImage * )image
{
    Converter converter;
    converter.image = image;

    NSMutableArray * images = [ NSMutableArray new ];

    for( auto i: converter.main() )
    {
        [ images addObject: i ];
    }

    return images;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for